# AWS VPC - Force EC2 to EC2 (ASAv) routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, asa

I am trying to force traffic from an EC2 instance to a Cisco ASAv within my VPC but having difficulty in every which way I try.  My setup is as follows;

PRIVATE SUBET > ASAv > PUBLIC SUBNET > AWS IGW

2 custom route tables; 1 for public which uses the igw and one for private which uses a default NAT instance.

I have used a EIP to map to ASAv outside private IP (public subnet) and within the ASAv I have set up a NAT forwarding rule to the EC2 instance sitting in the private subnet.  However, when I carry out a packet capture on the EC2 private subnet (using a secondary NIC to get to it via a separate public EIP RDP) I see no traffic (other than BC) coming out of the private NIC.  I have even put in static routes within the EC2 to send default route via ASA inside interface, but no joy.  Even if I remove the public NIC I dont recieve any response back from the EC2 sitting on the private subnet.

I see there is a local CIDR route populated automatically within every routing table (whether main or custom).

Am I right in thinking this route cannot be deleted?  How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem not more than a month ago. Make sure you check your AWS NACL's. For example, make sure you allow 0.0.0.0/0 https and http. for your AWS VPC routing, use the ENI for your inside ASA interface (should be on your private subnet). when you Make sure routing inside the ASA is pointing your 0.0.0.0/0 route to your outside interface GW (this will be the first ip address of your outside interface subnet. You will have also ensure your NAT statement's (Cisco ASAv) is set correctly.